# Update attributes from slightly different params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In the update action of my controller, I have this kind of code :

```rb
@loan.update_attributes(loan_params)
@loan.update_attributes(confirm: nil)
```

I want to make the same with only one request to the database. Do you know how to do it ?

Comment: Try with @loan.update_attributes(loan_params.merge!(confirm: nil))

Answer (score 1):

I think this can help you
Probably loan_params will be a hash generated as `loan => {:key => :val}`

SO the confirm attribute will be merge to the the loan hash for updating the `@loan`

```
loan_params['loan'].merge!(confirm : nil)
@loan.update_attributes(loan_params)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a Try with

```
loan_params[:confirm] = nil
@loan.update_attributes(loan_params)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
loan_params.merge!(:confirm => nil)
@loan.update_attributes(loan_params)
```

or

```
loan_params.merge!(confirm: nil)
@loan.update_attributes(loan_params)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

assuming

```
def
 params.require(:load).permit(:all_your_model_fields)
end

loan_params[:confirm] = nil
@loan.update(loan_params)
```

hope it help